# Clojure, using Enlive to extract raw HTML from a selector?

Tags: clojure, enlive

I need to retrieve some some **raw HTML** from a certain part of an HTML page.

I wrote the scraper and it grabs the appropriate div, but it returns a map of tags.

```
(:use [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(defn fetch-url [url]
 (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)))

(defn parse-test []
  (let [url "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0000928/"
        url-data (fetch-url url)
        id "a693025"]
    (first (html/select url-data [(keyword (str "#" id "-why"))]))))
```

This outputs:

```
{:tag :div, :attrs {:class "section", :id "a693025-why"}, :content ({:tag :h2, :attrs nil, :content ({:tag :span, :attrs {:class "title"}, :content ("Why is this medication prescribed?")})} {:tag :p, :attrs nil, :content ("Zolpidem is used to treat insomnia (difficulty falling asleep or staying asleep). Zolpidem belongs to a class of medications called sedative-hypnotics. It works by slowing activity in the brain to allow sleep.")})}
```

How do I convert this to raw html? I couldn't find any enlive function to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(apply str (html/emit* [(parse-test)]))
; => "<div class=\"section\" id=\"a693025-why\"><h2><span class=\"title\">Why is this medication prescribed?</span></h2><p>Zolpidem is used to treat insomnia (difficulty falling asleep or staying asleep). Zolpidem belongs to a class of medications called sedative-hypnotics. It works by slowing activity in the brain to allow sleep.</p></div>"
```